# Limit the Number of Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following

@articles = Article.find_all_by_published(true)

How would i limit this to display say 3 records only
but still needs to include the published(true) condition

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
@articles = Article.limit(3).find_all_by_published(true)
```